# Issue decoding JSON | Swift

Tags: swift

I am having an issue dynamically populating the `date` associated with each section.
The value of grouped is currently derived from grouping the raw JSON data by routeid

You can see that I am currently using a static value for date as a test, while `$0.key` represent the value of `myID` dynamically.

How can also add the dynamic value of `myDate` intead of "test"?

**Variables:**

```
var sections = [mySections]()
var structure = [myStructure]()
```

**Currently this is true**

`sections.map(\.id) == [8,4]`

**At the end this must be true as well**

`sections.map(\.date) == [2021-01-20, 2021-01-18]`

**Decoding:**

```
do {
      let decoder = JSONDecoder()
      let res = try decoder.decode([myStructure].self, from: data)
      let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: res, by: { $0.myID })
      _ = grouped.keys.sorted()
      sections = grouped.map { mySections(date: "test", id: $0.key, items: $0.value) }
      .sorted { $0.id > $1.id }
}
```

**Struct:**

```
struct mySections {
    let date : String
    let id : Int
    var items : [myStructure]
}

struct myStructure: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let type: String
    let myID: Int
    let myDate: String
}
```

**Example JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Jeff",
    "type": "large",
    "myID": 8,
    "myDate": "2021-01-20"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jessica",
    "type": "small",
    "myID": 4,
    "myDate": "2021-01-18"
  },
  {
    "name": "Beth",
    "type": "medium",
    "myID": 4,
    "myDate": "2021-01-18"
  }
]
```

Comment: I am trying to produce the output and run your current code. What is `routeStructure` meant to be ? Is it a type of `mySections` ?

Comment: Apologies, that was typo. Please see the updated post

Comment: Please see Rob's answer below, I tested it and works a treat with your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want it grouped by both id number and date string? I would create a `Hashable` structure for those two values.

```swift
struct Section {
    let date: String
    let id: Int
    var items: [Item]
}

extension Section {
    struct Header: Hashable {
        let date: String
        let id: Int
    }
}

struct Item: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let type: String
    let myID: Int
    let myDate: String
}
```

And

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let res = try decoder.decode([Item].self, from: data)
let sections = Dictionary(grouping: res) { Section.Header(date: $0.myDate, id: $0.myID) }
    .sorted { $0.key.id > $1.key.id }
    .map { Section(date: $0.key.date, id: $0.key.id, items: $0.value) }
```

Comment: Forgive the renaming of the types. Re `myStructure` to `Item`, I wanted to (a) follow capitalization conventions (we never have type names that start with a lowercase letter); and (b) `Structure` is just too ambiguous. While I was renaming stuff, I’m not sure why you’d call it `mySections` when (a) each one represents a single section; and (b) same capitalization concerns.